# How can I process json file and display some data in form of charts in django

Tags: json, django, chart.js

Basically, I have implemented Sentiment analysis for the Amazon review dataset in python. Now I want to make a web app for it. I try to look on google for it but all the projects are for Twitter data. Till now I make a Django app which can take json file from the user and display the success message. Any ideas on how to load the json file in my script and put these data on the charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model to upload the file. Create a director `upload` for uploading at root of your project

```
from django.db import models

class JSONFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads')
```

You can use a form:

```
from django import forms

class JSONFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a file',
        help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
    )
```

Create templates as 'chart.html' to show your chart accordingly and 'upload.html' to render above form

In your **views.py**:

```
from forms import JSONFileForm
from models import JSONFile
from django.shortcuts import render
def chart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JSONFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newfile = JSONFile(file = request.FILES['file'])
            newfile.save()
            json.dumps(request.FILES['file'])
            #format your data here
            return render(request,"chart.html",{}) #pass data context in {} as dict
        else:
            form = JSONFileForm(request.POST)
    else:
         form = JSONFileForm()
         return render(request,"upload.html",{"form":form})
```

Comment: I am little confuse here. What exactly should be changes in url.py and HTML files so that the rendering is possible.